# Nashorn, compile once for multiple scopes, like for Rhino

Tags: javascript, java, rhino, nashorn

I'm investigating the possibility of moving a huge project based on rhino to nashorn. That said project has thousands of scopes (~instances) running in one rhino compiled script (of 10k+ lines of javascript).

What I know how to do:

- Multiple nashorn engines will give me multiple/indepedent scopes. Works but comsumes waaaayyyyy too much memory (1000 engines...)
- *eval* a string on a nashorn CompiledScript. Works too but makes it nearly impossible to pass complex java objects/instances to the function i want to call.

Example of what I can do with Rhino and want to be able to do with Nashorn:

```
String SOURCE = "var i = 0; function add(a) { i += a; return i; }";
System.out.println("=== RHINO ===");
Context cx = Context.enter();
cx.setOptimizationLevel(Context.FEATURE_STRICT_EVAL); // optimization level 9

Script script = cx.compileString(SOURCE, "mySource", 1, null); // compile once

Scriptable scope1 = cx.initStandardObjects(); // 1st re-use
Scriptable scope2 = cx.initStandardObjects(); // 2nd re-use

script.exec(cx, scope1);
script.exec(cx, scope2);

Function add1 = (Function) scope1.get("add", scope1);
Function add2 = (Function) scope2.get("add", scope2);

try {
    Object r1 = add1.call(cx, scope1, scope1, new Object[]{6});
    System.out.println("result1=" + r1); // print 6
    r1 = add1.call(cx, scope1, scope1, new Object[]{4});
    System.out.println("result1=" + r1); // print 10
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    Object r2 = add2.call(cx, scope2, scope2, new Object[]{9});
    System.out.println("result2=" + r2); // prints 9
    r2 = add2.call(cx, scope2, scope2, new Object[]{3});
    System.out.println("result2=" + r2); // prints 12
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

Context.exit();
```

In the example above, I compile the script once and use multiple scopes to isolate my different execution instances.
How can I do such a thing with Nashorn? Keep in mind that in my real project I want to invoke much more complex functions that would take javascript or java instances in parameters.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Nashorn supports loadWithNewGlobal primitive (https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-loadWithNewGlobal). This primitive allows you to load scripts in *new global* scope - each having it's own definitions for "Object", "Function", etc. It appears this may help for your use case. There is also inter-scope object method/property access support. i.e., you can pass and return objects to/from scripts evaluated in different scopes - appropriate wrapping/mirroring is taken care by Nashorn.